# Displaying commit history from non-github git repository in my github account?

Tags: git, version-control, github, repository

A couple of years ago, I committed some work to a git repo that is stored on a university server instead of on github.com. This is where that repo lives: http://charm.cs.uiuc.edu/cgi-bin/gitweb2.cgi?p=charm.git;a=summary

Now, I'm trying to use my github account as sort of a "supplementary CV" while applying for jobs. I'd like to show the [charm.cs.uiuc.edu/...](http://charm.cs.uiuc.edu/cgi-bin/gitweb2.cgi?p=charm.git;a=summary) git commit history on my github.com account. Is it possible to link a repo like this with my github.com account?

Note that I don't actually want to store the repo on github.com; I just want the commit history appear in my github.com user account.

Comment: hi did you find a solution to this problem ? I am facing a similar issue.

Comment: No, I haven't found a good way to merge stuff from a non-github git repository into the github profile commit history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create user pages and paste a screenshot or an HTML page or something like but, but otherwise you need to store the repo there.